# Shiny selectInput flips to the top after display

Tags: r, shiny

My Shiny app has 2 input a) A drop down list b) A list with a scroll bar. I find that when I select a value by scrolling down, after the command is executed the scroll window flips back to the top of the 20 of the list and does not stay on the selected value.

This is the code in 
server.R

```
 # Analyze and display bowler's plots
    output$bowlerPlot <- renderPlot({  
    load("./bowler.RData")
        IPLBowlers <-b        
        # Render dynamic UI
        output$bowlerFunctionList = renderUI({
        selectInput('bowlerFunc', 'Choose function',choices=IPLBowlerFuncs,selected=input$bowlerFunc)
        })
        output$bowlerList = renderUI({
        selectInput('bowler', 'Choose chart type',choices=IPLBowlers,selected=input$bowler,
         selectize=FALSE, size=20)
        })

        analyzeIPLBowlers(input$bowler,input$bowlerFunc)

    })
```

and 
ui.R

```
 # Application title
      titlePanel("Analyze bowlers"),                            
      fluidRow(
      column(3,
                uiOutput("bowlerFunctionList"), 
                uiOutput("bowlerList")                                       
               ),                                
               # Show a plot of the generated distribution        
               column(6,
                      plotOutput("bowlerPlot")
                ),

            )
         )
```

Please let me know this can be fixed.

Comment: The structure of our code is not right.  While a `renderUI` function can include one (or many) `renderPlot` function, the reverse is not true (and in your case leads to unpredictable results!).  I am amazed that you get anything displayed at all.  Make sure that `renderPlot` does not include the two `renderUI` functions and it should work (but are you sure you need server side code, i.e. `renderUI` for your use case??)

Comment: Thanks Enzo. Not sure how to modify because each renderUI coresponds to a UI list.

Comment: Managed to simplify one of the tabs without the renderUI.

Comment: Enzo - I redid the entire design and removed the multiple renderUIs. It works fine now. You can answer and I will accept.

Comment: Thanks  @Tinniam V. Ganesh. I've added a `updateSelectInput`example that may be relevant to your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of our code is not right.

While a `renderUI` function can include one (or many) `renderPlot` function, the reverse is usually not true (and in your case leads to unpredictable results!).

I am amazed that you get anything displayed at all. Make sure that renderPlot does not include the two renderUI functions and it should work.

If it is just the matter to update the `selectInput` server side,  you can use `updateSelectInput`.

Just as a possible example of `updateSelectInput` use, I've lifted from `Function reference version 0.14.2` the following code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  p("The checkbox group controls the select input"),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Input checkbox",
                     c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C")),
  selectInput("inSelect", "Select input",
              c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    x <- input$inCheckboxGroup
    # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
    if (is.null(x))
      x <- character(0)  
    # Can also set the label and select items
    updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect",
                      label = paste("Select input label", length(x)),
                      choices = x,
                      selected = tail(x, 1)
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```